# Object is not iterable when I SELECT from DB

Tags: python, postgresql

I am learning databases on python with pools and cursors and I am getting stuck making a SELECT to my database to bring my information back.

When I try to get the information put it on a list and iterate, Python throws me an error such as TypeError: 'Usuario' object is not iterable. Here is the code of DAO:

```
from usuario import Usuario
from logger_base import logger
from cursor import CursorPool

class UsuarioDao:
    __SELECCIONAR = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY id_usuario'
    __INSERTAR = 'INSERT INTO usuarios(username, password) VALUES(%s,%s)'
    __ACTUALIZAR = 'UPDATE usuarios SET username=%s, password=%s WHERE id_usuario=%s'
    __ELIMINAR = 'DELETE FROM usuarios where id_usuario=%s'
    
    @classmethod
    def seleccionar(cls):
        with CursorPool() as cursor:
            logger.debug(cursor.mogrify(cls.__SELECCIONAR))
            cursor.execute(cls.__SELECCIONAR)
            registros = cursor.fetchall()
            usuarios = []
            for registro in registros:
                usuarios = Usuario(registro[0], registro[1], registro[2])
            return usuarios
        
    @classmethod
    def insertar(cls, usuario):
        with CursorPool() as cursor:
            valores = (usuario.get_username(), usuario.get_password())
            logger.debug(cursor.mogrify(cls.__INSERTAR))
            cursor.execute(cls.__INSERTAR, valores)
            return cursor.rowcount

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Insertamos un nuevo registro
    #usuario = Usuario(username='Ramon', password='542')
    #usuario_insertado = UsuarioDao.insertar(usuario)
    #logger.debug(f'usuario añadido: {usuario_insertado}')

    usuarios = UsuarioDao.seleccionar()
    for usuario in usuarios:
        logger.debug(usuario)
```

My cursor and conection code is this:

```
from conexion import Conexion
from logger_base import logger

class CursorPool:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__conn = None
        self.__cursor = None
    
    #Incio de with
    def __enter__(self):
        logger.debug(f'Inicio de with metodo __enter__ {self.__conn}')
        self.__conn = Conexion.obtenerConexion()
        self.__cursor = self.__conn.cursor()
        return self.__cursor
    
    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback):
        logger.debug('Se ejecuta método __exit__()')
        if exception_value:
            self.__conn.rollback()
            logger.debug(f'Ocurrió una excepción: {exception_value}')
        else:
            self.__conn.commit()
            logger.debug('Commit de la transacción')
        #Cerramos el cursor
        self.__cursor.close()
        #Regresamos la conexion al pool
        Conexion.liberarConexion(self.__conn)
```

```
from logger_base import logger
from psycopg2 import pool
import sys

class Conexion:
    __DATABASE = 'lab_final'
    __USERNAME = 'postgres'
    __PASSWORD = 'admin'
    __DB_PORT = '5432'
    __HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    __MIN_CON = 1
    __MAX_CON = 5
    __pool = None
    
    @classmethod
    def obtenerPool(cls):
        if cls.__pool is None:
            try:
                cls.__pool = pool.SimpleConnectionPool(
                                                    cls.__MIN_CON,
                                                    cls.__MAX_CON,
                                                    host = cls.__HOST,
                                                    user=cls.__USERNAME,
                                                    password=cls.__PASSWORD,
                                                    port=cls.__DB_PORT,
                                                    database=cls.__DATABASE)
                logger.debug(f'Creacion del pool exitosa {cls.__pool}')
                return cls.__pool
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f'Error al crear el pool de conexiones:{e}')
                sys.exit()
        else:
            return cls.__pool
        
    @classmethod
    def obtenerConexion(cls):
        #Obtener conexion del pool
        conexion = cls.obtenerPool().getconn()
        logger.debug(f'Conexion obtenida del pool: {conexion}')
        return conexion
    
    @classmethod
    def liberarConexion(cls, conexion):
        #Regresar el objeto de conexion al pool
        cls.obtenerPool().putconn(conexion)
        logger.debug(f'Regresamos la conexion al pool: {conexion}')
        logger.debug(f'Estado del pool: {cls.__pool}')
    
    @classmethod
    def cerrarConexiones(cls):
        #Cerrar el pool y todas sus conexiones
        cls.obtenerPool().closeall()
```

And my user object is a simple object that have id, username and password

```
from logger_base import logger

class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, id_usuario = None, username = None, password = None):
        self.__id_usuario = id_usuario
        self.__username = username
        self.__password = password
    
    def __str__(self):
        return (f'ID usuario: {self.__id_usuario}, Username: {self.__username}, Password: {self.__password}')
            
    def get_id_usuario(self):
        return self.__id_usuario
    
    def set_id_usuario(self, id_usuario):
        self.__id_usuario = id_usuario
        
    def get_username(self):
        return self.__username
    
    def set_username(self, username):
        self.__username = username
    
    def get_password(self):
        return self.__password
    
    def set_password(self, password):
        self.__password = password
```

Firs of all I thought that probably the error might be that I have only one user on my database and python don't make a list but I have more than one user on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to make a list of `usuario` here:

```
usuarios = []
```

but then you're overwriting it with a single object here:

```
usuarios = Usuario(registro[0], registro[1], registro[2])
```

So only a single object is getting returned from this method.

What you want is to `.append()` the objects to the list:

```
usuarios.append(Usuario(registro[0], registro[1], registro[2]))
```

Which will return a list of `Usuario` objects that you can iterate over.